# bash: get size and [x,y]-element from a list of different size arrays

Tags: bash

BASH: I have a list of array of different size from an external config sourced file:

```
declare -a line0=( 00 01 02    )
declare -a line1=( 10 11       )
...
declare -a line9=( 90 91 92 93 )
rows=9
```

Getting the size of a single array works as so:

```
${#line0[@]}
```

this can be practical only for few arrays like in the example.

I need to get the array size in a for loop. I tryed this:

```
for ((r=0;r<rows;r++)) do
   line="line$r"
   echo line:$line
   cols="${#$line[@]}"    # 1st assignment
   cols="${#line$r[@]}"   # 2nd assignment
done
```

but got 'bad substitution' error for both assignment.

Then, supposing to know the max cols value, I need to extract the single element from arrays with two nested loops. I tryed so:

```
cols=4
for ((r=0;r<rows;r++)) do
   line="line$r"
   echo line:$line
   for ((c=0;c<cols;c++)) do
      val=${$line[$c]}    # 1st assignment
      val=${line$r[$c]}   # 2nd assignment
      echo val:$val
   done
done
```

but got 'bad substitution' error for both assignment.

Edit: what is the right method to get size and [x,y]-element from a list of different size arrays?

I looked for other questions, but there are solutions for same sized arrays only

Comment: Soo what is your question? `I have a list of array of different size` Is that your _actual input_? Did you consider representing that input differently, as just lines of space separated numbers? Or one array of elements containing space separated numbers? As you noticed, working with such structure is unpleasant... there are just better ways. `here are solutions` What problem are you trying to solve? Did you consider using something else than bash if you want to model a matrix? Like Perl or Python? Or Awk? Or literally anything else than bash?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `indirect reference` with `declare -n ref=varname`.
Would you please try:

```
for ((r = 0; r < rows; r++)); do
    declare -n line="line$r"        # now "line" will be a reference to the array
    cols="${#line[@]}"              # you can access the array with the name "line"
    echo "line:$r cols:$cols"
done
```

BTW it might be better to say `rows=10`, because the count of rows is 10 (IMHO).

Comment: I see the 9 now. Shouldn't that just be `r <= rows` given `rows=9`? i guess either way works...

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for the comment. That will make sense. But I'd prefer to saying `rows=10` for clarity because the count of rows is 10.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem with a nebulous variable name like `rows`, we don't know if it's meant to be `maxRowNr` or `numRows` or something else. Either one would make sense but the code as written assumes it means `maxRowNr` when it's initialized but then `numRows` when it's referenced. That's one benefit of a tool/language like awk that starts generated arrays at 1 instead of 0 - `maxRowNr` and `numRows` would have the same value so you can't confuse them in the code.

Comment: Oh, that's right. I've updated my comment not to push my own opinion :).

Comment: WORK thank you. It is impossible to put formatted code in comments, so see below

Comment: If `line` is an array variable, `$line` is equivalent to `${line[0]}`
and `echo "$line"` will print `00`, `01` ... It is common with bash array,
not related to the indirect reference.

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be

```
#!/bin/bash

source configfile

for arrname in ${!line*}; do
    [[ $arrname =~ ^line[0-9]+$ ]] || continue
    declare -n arrptr=$arrname
    printf 'line:%d size:%d\n' "${arrname#line}" "${#arrptr[@]}"
done
```

This assumes all arrays whose names match the regular expression `^line[0-9]+$` are of interest.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare -p $(seq 1 "$rows"|xargs -I {} echo line{})|awk -F'[][ =]' '{print $3,$(NF-2)+1}' 

line1 2
line2 2
line3 3
line4 3
line5 2
line6 2
line7 1
line8 2
line9 4
```

- `seq 1 "$rows"|xargs -I {} echo line{}` list all array-names
- `declare -p  <array-name>` display the attributes and values
- `awk -F'[][ =]' '{print $3,$(NF-2)+1}'` print array-name and size

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score -1):

like so is perfect:

```
declare -a line0=( 00 01 02    )
declare -a line1=( 10 11       )
...
declare -a line9=( 90 91 92 93 )
rows=10
for ((r=0;r<rows;r++)) do
   declare -n line="line$r"
   #echo line:"$line"
   cols="${#line[@]}"
   echo cols:$cols
   for ((c=0;c<cols;c++)) do
      val=${line[$c]}
      echo r:$r c:$c val:$val
   done
done
```

The only strange think is that printing "line" return something non-sense:

```
echo line:"$line"
```

show (seems 1st element of lineN):

```
line:00
line:10
...
```

but I do not need to print that, only to use as refs, works, thanks

Comment: `line` is an array; `$line` is the same as `${line[0]}` (ie, the first element in the array); if you want to print the entire array then use `${line[@]}`